# I have Hebrew Bible files in XML with one format but i need it in TEI p5 format. Is there anyway i can convert it?

Tags: xml, hebrew, digital, oxygenxml, tei

I have a [Tanach.us](https://tanach.us/) xml file with the following file format

```
<Tanach>
   <teiHeader>
     ...
   <teiHeader>

   <tanach>
     <book>
       <names>
       </names>
       <c>
          <v>
            <w> </w> or <q> </q> or <k> </k> containing Hebrew text.
          </v>
       </c>
     </book>
   </tanach>

   <notes>
   </notes>

</Tanach>
```

But i want it in the following format

```
<TEI>
<teiHeader>

</teiHeader>
 <text>
  <body>
   <p>This is about the shortest TEI document imaginable.</p>
  </body>
 </text>
</TEI>
```

Also these contents are from Hebrew Bible, if I am using Oxgarage for conversion, the content which is read right to left in Hebrew, get disturbed.

Comment: This is what XSLT is for.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how it can be done? I do not know XSLT n new to tei

Comment: No, sorry, this site is for answering coding questions, not for writing tutorials. There are plenty of books and tutorials you can turn to.